# How to subclass SKnode to create a scene with multiple independent 'lanes'?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am building [a 2d game with four lanes](http://fredstidston.co.uk/macrotopia5/) and each lane should have its own identical coordinates system and logic

What is the proper way to subclass SKNode and add it to the SKScene?

The lane spacing and height will adapt to screen dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not much of a brief to go on, 
It all depends on the degree of variance between your four different lanes. When I say variance I mean like will they need different stored properties? How many unique methods will each lane have. Either way create a base Class lane inheriting from SKNode, brain storm and think of all the properties and methods which will be generic across all lanes and add them to this class. You may find you don't need to subclass this type when you are done. Either way you can then always inherit from this type at a later point as your scope expands and you find you have defined the individual lane behaviour.

Once you have your base class type you can then just add 4 instances of the class to the scene.

or if you choose you can add 2 base class types and say 2 types which have inherited from the base class.

OK so you create a new .swift (I'm presuming your using Swift) delete anything in there that is not a comment then write for the base class

```
import SpriteKit

class ______: SKNode  {

    init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public func update() {        

    }

    public func updateDidEnd() {

    }

    deinit {
        print("DEBUG: ________: deinit")
    }

}
```

This is the close to a boiler plate I use when sub classing SKNode. Where it gives _______ just add the name of the class

When you want to sub class from this class just do the same but replace SKNode on the second line with whatever name you assign to the base class. You can keep doing this as much as you like.

Look at encapsulation in particular to identify what you want to put in there to start with. When subclassing think towards polymorphism it takes a bit of getting used to but once it clicks it makes writing code quicker.

You have lots of options

Comment: The part I don't know about is architecturally how to put these subclasses in a separate file and then add them into my scene file as properties